# An elegant way of page-to-page iterating through boto.resultset.ResultSet

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, mechanicalturk

Is there an elegant way of paging through `boto.resultset.ResultSet`, e.g.:

```
amt = boto.mturk.connection.MTurkConnection()
qualid = "XXX"
quals = amt.get_qualifications_for_qualification_type( qualid, page_size=100, page_number=1 )
# quals becomes boto.resultset.ResultSet with just 100 items
```

The last query can return several pages of results. Given that there are many queries in `boto` returning several pages of results, isn't there any elegant way to iterate over all the results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, I'm using my own solution:

```
def get_entire_resultset( query, *args, **kargs ):
   ps = 100; pn = 1
   objs = query( *args, page_size=ps, page_number=pn, **kargs )
   total_downloaded = ps
   pn += 1
   total = int(objs.TotalNumResults)
   while total_downloaded<total:
      objs.extend( query( *args, page_size=ps, page_number=pn, **kargs ) )
      total_downloaded += ps
      pn += 1
   return objs
```

That is used as follows:

```
quals = get_entire_resultset( amt.get_qualifications_for_qualification_type, qualid )
```